# Logged in or not?

Tags: discussion, bug

There are several related items in meta, but I can’t tell whether they are the duplicates to this.  And if they were, I can’t put an image in a comment, so …

[image]
[image]

These were displayed on the same page after I clicked “Post.”  I then clicked on my avatar and got the log in form.  Logged in and got the “prove you’re human," which hangs on Safari before displaying the CAPTCHA.  Went to another browser, clicked “ask question” and the saved draft was missing most of my text.  I went back to the hung “human verification” and refreshed the page, which got rid of the verification.  I then copied the text, pasted it in the other browser and clicked “post.”  Got another verification, but it doesn’t hang in DuckDuckGo, so I was able to post it.

Comment: The images were correct in the preview but one was missing after posting.  OK after I deleted both and added them again.

Comment: It sounds like you were logged out while you were writing the post. It can happen automatically due to suspicious activity (I was once quickly switching between wifi networks and triggered it, for example) or even manually by a moderator (I'd say very unlikely here).

Comment: I used paste to replace the partial post with the full thing, click post, and both the full and the partial got posted as separate questions!